On IOS devices, the vertical swipes are not disabled. They work well on andriod devices, but not on IOS. I have build my app in next.js
I have disabled verical swipes on my app. it works fine on andriod devices but on ios, there is still a dragging effect on screen. how i can prevent that ?
This is my code in index.js
if (webApp) {
  if (webApp.expand) {
    webApp.expand();
  }
  if (webApp.platform === supportedPlatforms.android || webApp.platform === supportedPlatforms.ios) {
    webApp.isVerticalSwipesEnabled = false;
  }
  // Request the app to expand to full screen
}

I tried verious methods including simply palcingwebApp.isVerticalSwipesEnabled = false;and it works well on dnriod but not on IOS.
